# How To Make HTTPS IP:PORT Website At Apache Server

Tags: apache-http-server, ip

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName   68.183.182.49
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
    <FilesMatch "\.(?:cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I make my DOMAIN:PORT website traffic switch from HTTP to HTTPS? the code above is the code that I have done in the default-ssl.conf file.
Please help everyone. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache, you can add the following code to Apache Config file (usually `default.conf`) for the HTTP port (usually port 80):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 68.183.182.49
    Redirect / https://68.183.182.49
</VirtualHost>
```